# What are these incoming connections in my wireless router logs?

Tags: router

I am analyzing my incoming connection log from my Linksys E1000 wireless router. [Bonus points if anyone can tell me how long these routers store logs because I can't figure it out anywhere, so I can't really correlate well.]

I have three entries. One is a known entry as it shows my friend's ISP and says the port that I have Mumble server configured on.

The other two entries are from unknown IPs. One resolves to a Serbian IP. The other one somewhere just as concerning. The destination port is 54876.

What am I seeing here? The only port I have forwarded in my router is for Mumble/Murmur. Isn't everything else implicit deny? What is port 54876 used for and is this scanning or what could this entry be?

The syntax in the entry is `'External IP' from wan to port 54876 is accepted`

Comment: If you're running Skype or P2P software (Torrent client, etc) it may cause these incoming connections.

Comment: I don't run P2P, but I do have a Skype web plugin (extension) for Chrome..wonder if it somehow triggers anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One on several possibilities is that it is just the result of an outgoing connect.  You connect to port 80 on a web server(or any other port/server), but on your end the connecting port is **randomly** selected.

Logs on routers are usually very short lived, they usually have room for a few 100 or maybe a 1000 if your really lucky and that is it.

If you want to do some serious analyst you will have to find a compatible open source router firmware like Tomato or DD-WRT.  Otherwise you probably won't be able to access the logs.

Large groups of bot nets scan ports and ips randomly to avoid being detected as port scans.  In a year or so I have 62,000+ ip address attempt connect to different unused ports.  I add 100 a day or so.

Comment: Wonder if even an advertisement on the web could show up in my router logs somehow? I don't know of accessing any web server (going to any website) that would resolve to that...but I suppose it's certainly possible and this sounds like a very logical explanation. I've since upgraded routers and am hoping the stock firmware does some decent logging. If not, I'll look into something like DD-WRT.

Comment: @shift_tab if you use whois on the 2 ip addresses who do they resolved to?

Comment: I'll have to look back at my logs. One was in Serbia and I don't remember the other. I've upgraded wireless routers since first posting this question. I'm hoping the logging is a bit better. I have a feeling I'll be desiring more, so maybe I'll try out DD-WRT or some other open-source firmware.